# How to make a POST request for each file in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

I have an array of drag'n'dropped files inside angular component. I would like to make a POST request to `http://some.url` for each of them. I'm trying to do the following:

**drop.component.ts**

```
public drop(event) {  
    * somehow set droppedFiles *

    let observables = [];

    this.droppedFiles.forEach(file => observables.push(this.uploadFile(file)));
    forkJoin(observables); 
}  

public uploadFile(image) {
    return this.imagesService.saveImage(image, this.tigerId).pipe(first()).subscribe(
        (data: ISaveImageResponse) => {
            console.log(data);

            return;
        },
        error => {
            console.error(error);

            return;
        }
    );
}
```

**images.service.ts**

```
public saveImage(image: File): Observable<ISaveImageResponse> {
    let imageInfo = {
        name: null, type: null, image: null
    };

    imageInfo.name = [image.name, Validators.required];
    imageInfo.type = [image.type, Validators.required];
    imageInfo.image = null;

    let form = this.formBuilder.group(imageInfo);
    form.get('image').setValue(image);

    const formModel = this.prepareFormData(form);

    return this.http.post<any>(
        'http://some.url',
        formModel
    ).pipe(
        map((imageInfo: any) => {
            return imageInfo
        }),
        catchError((error, caught) => {
            return EMPTY;
        })
    );
}
```

If I drop single file, this works fine. But if there are multiple files, requests become *pending* but I can't see them logged to server (which is express.js server).
What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

I've updated code to be actual: now `uploadImage()` returns `Observable` and requests are called from `forkJoin()`

**UPDATE 2**

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

After some time requests being *pending* I get the following error in server console:

```
(node:1291) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 
11 field listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

But no info about request happening at all (for any request I do, for example `console.log('POST /images');`)

**UPDATE 3**

server-side code for handling POST requests:

**server.js**

```
const server = express();
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

server.use(
    session({
        store: new RedisStore({
            url: config.redisStore.url
        }),
        secret: config.redisStore.secret,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    })
);
server.use( passport.initialize() );
server.use( passport.session() );
server.use( cors({ origin: '*' }) );
server.use( bp.json() );
server.use( express.static('uploads') );
server.use( require('./image.routes') );

const port = 9901;

server.listen(port, () => {
    const dir = __dirname + '/uploads';
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }
    console.log('We are live on ' + port);
});
```

**image.routes.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const formidable = require('express-formidable');
const path = require('path');
let router = express.Router();

router.post('/images',
    formidable({
        encoding: 'utf-8',
        uploadDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'uploads'),
        multiples: true,
        keepExtensions: true
    }),
    (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('\nPOST /images');

        const image = req.fields;
        const data = req.files;

        image.path = data.image.path;

        const file = fs.createReadStream(image.path);

        createImage(image).then(  // createImage() saves image info to db
            result => {
                if (result) {
                    res.status(200).send(result);
                } else {
                    console.error("Cannot save image");
                    res.status(400).send("Cannot save image");
                }
        }).catch(e => console.error(e.stack));
});  

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: first thing, the uploadFile method does not return a promise, so putting them in an array and doing promise.all does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use `Promise.all` to handle [Rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) requests.

You can use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to make multiple Observale request at once,

```
public drop(event) {  
* somehow set droppedFiles *

   let observables = []

   this.droppedFiles.forEach(file => observables.push(this.uploadFile(file)));
   Rx.Observable.forkJoin(observables)
}
```

Also your `uploadFile` function is not returning an observable

```
   public uploadFile(image) {
      return this.imagesService.saveImage(image, this.tigerId).pipe(first())
   }
```

check out example number 5 [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Comment: Well, it still doesn't work. Can it be the problem with my server?

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you post which error you are getting

Comment: I tried this but the result is still the same. I'm thinking there is also some problem with server. I've updated my answer, can you, please, check it

Comment: Show us the server side code thats handling the posts

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'map' or 'for' instead forEach.

```
public drop(event) {  
    * somehow set droppedFiles *

    Promise.all(this.droppedFiles.map(file => this.uploadFile(file))); 
}
```

Comment: uploadFile() should return promise object. `public uploadFile(image) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.imagesService.saveImage(image, this.tigerId).pipe(first()).subscribe(
      (data: ISaveImageResponse) => {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);

        reject(error);
      }
    );
  });
}`

Comment: This also doesn't help. I suppose there is also some error with my server. Can it be so?

Comment: There is nothing happens. Even `console.log('\nPOST /images');` doesn't get called

Comment: Could you, please, recommend what to google to solve (or, at least, understand) the problem?

Comment: Put your project to github and give link to it. I'll try to look for the errors

Comment: Well, the problem is that project is part of my job, so I can't share the whole repo